# Does PayPal support direct debit payments?

Tags: paypal

Can you help me to find answer if PayPal supports direct debit payments? I tried to find it in google or paypal documentation but still not sure. I know it's possible to link PayPal account to bank account but what about making payments this way to PayPal merchant account.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You wish for customers to pay directly with their bank account? They can do this through any PayPal checkout, and it's done via "instant transfer" if they have a credit card available as a backup funding source in the event the bank transfer fails to debit the funds.

So basically, if I'm understanding your questions correctly, offer PayPal as a payment method and customers who sign into their account can pay with their checking or savings account.